# JDBC check if a connection can warantee it will commit without errors

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, connection

Is there a way of checking if a connection will commit without throwing an exception?

I know deferrable foreign key constraints are only enforced at transaction commit.

Does the JDBC (java 6) API provide any method to ask the database whether all operations since the connection began (or last commit) would be successfull?

Regards,
Pablo.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. The process of committing takes sometime and in any moment connection can be lost(imagine somebody unplugs the cabel). So no guarantees here. Just catch the exceptions - that why they were invented.

Comment: @vladimit: So how does an XADatasource handle a two phase commit?

Comment: @vladmir: I may have worded my question wrong: In the case of deferrable constraints, is there any way of asking the database through jdbc to perform a constraint check?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Oracle database you can check if there are any deferred constraint violations before commit with:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE");
```